# Unable to destroy widgets created by function in tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, widget, destroy

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")

var1 = StringVar()

def create():
    twoLabel = Label(root,text="meh",)
    twoLabel.place(x=20,y=300)

    threeTextEntry = Entry(root, textvariable=var1)
    threeTextEntry.place(x=20,y=400)  

def destroy():    
    twoLabel.destroy()
    threeTextEntry.destroy()

zeroButton = tk.Button(root, text="create", width=8, fg="black", bg="gold", command=create)
zeroButton.place(x=20,y=100)

oneButton = tk.Button(root, text="destroy", width=8, fg="black", bg="gold", command=destroy)
oneButton.place(x=20,y=200)

twoLabel = Label(root,text="meh",)
twoLabel.place(x=20,y=300)

threeTextEntry = Entry(root, textvariable=var1)
threeTextEntry.place(x=20,y=400)
```

The widgets are created, I can destroy them initially with the widget and then recreate them.  But then I can no longer destory them after the widgets have been recreated by the function.  What am I doing wrong here?  Sorry I'm new to tkinter - thanks.

Comment: This isn't a tkinter problem, it's a normal python problem. `twoLabel and `threeTextentry are local variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to define your variables `twoLabel` and `threeTextEntry` as `globals` ,because when you are creating these variables in the function they are `local variables` and you can not reach them from another functions.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")

var1 = StringVar()


def create():
    global twoLabel
    global threeTextEntry
    twoLabel = Label(root,text="meh",)
    twoLabel.place(x=20,y=300)

    threeTextEntry = Entry(root, textvariable=var1)
    threeTextEntry.place(x=20,y=400)

def destroy():
    twoLabel.destroy()
    threeTextEntry.destroy()

zeroButton = tk.Button(root, text="create", width=8, fg="black", bg="gold", command=create)
zeroButton.place(x=20,y=100)

oneButton = tk.Button(root, text="destroy", width=8, fg="black", bg="gold", command=destroy)
oneButton.place(x=20,y=200)

global twoLabel
global threeTextEntry
twoLabel = Label(root,text="meh",)
twoLabel.place(x=20,y=300)

threeTextEntry = Entry(root, textvariable=var1)
threeTextEntry.place(x=20,y=400)

root.mainloop()
```